# ZigZag Quadruples

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I've seen this interesting question, and wonder if there are more ways to approach it:

> Given a permutation of numbers from 1 to n, count the number of
> quadruples indices (i,j,k,l) such that i<j<k<l and A[i]<A[k]<A[j]<A[l]

e.g.

Input     : [1,3,2,6,5,4] 
Output : 1 (1,3,2,6)

Desired algorithm is O(n^2)

Approach:
I've tried to solve it using stack, in a similiar manner to [Leetcode 132 pattern](https://leetcode.com/problems/132-pattern/) - but it seems to fail.

```
def get_smaller_before(A):
    smaller_before  = [0] * len(A)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(i):
            if A[j] < A[i]:
                smaller_before[i] += 1
    return smaller_before

def get_larger_after(A):
    larger_after = [0] * len(A)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
            if A[i] < A[j]:
                larger_after[i] += 1
    return larger_after

def countQuadrples(nums):
    if not nums:
        return False
    smaller_before      = get_smaller_before(nums)
    larger_after        = get_larger_after(nums)
    counter             = 0
    stack = []
    for j in reversed(range(1, len(nums))):
        # i < j < k < l
        # smaller_before < nums[k] < nums[j] < larger_after
        while stack and nums[stack[-1]] < nums[j]:
            counter += smaller_before[j] * larger_after[stack[-1]]
            stack.pop()
        stack.append(j)
    return counter
```

Does anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is some sort of 2-dimensional tree that allows you to quickly answer the question "How many points after `k` have value bigger than `A[j]`," and the question "How many points before j have value less than `A[k]`?"  These will usually be time `O(n log(n))` to build and those queries should run in time something like `O(log(n)^2))`.

A number of such data structures exist.  One option is a variant on a [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).  You you turn each array element into a point with x-coordinate the position in the array and y-coordinate being its value.  And your queries are just counting how many elements are in a box.

And now you can do a double loop over all `j, k` and count how many zig-zag quadruples have those as the inner pair.